# Usb Flash Drive Serial Number

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-mass-storage

This question is not exactly about code but rather knowing more about Usb flash drive. I am using serial number information  to generate Pseudo random number, later use that value in my project.I have some `n` number of flash devices from different companies, when ever I read the serial number of individual some shows a 20 digit value and some as no serial number. Few example values are as below:

```
SanDisk- 4C530001251204119145
Strontium- CCYYMMDDHHmmSSCAU2L8
Hp- 0000000000000000EC00
```

Can somebody tell is this 20-digit numbering is a standard definition or something else? The reason for looking for this information is , I have found this [pdf: Pen DriveTM 2.0 Specification](ftp://ftp.wintel.fi/docs/PenDrive/PenDrive20Spec.pdf)  define some standard for pen drive serial number. Few Flash drive serial numbers are so random that I just can't understand what is that all about.

Any insights are greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: There are up to *three* serial numbers on an USB mass storage stick: One in the USB string descriptors (optional), one in the SCSI layer (also optional) and one on the flash media as part of the file system. Each may be a different "number" string.

Comment: Is it a hexa value or random value? Links to related documents are helpful

Comment: SCSI has no public linkable documents AFAIK. And the USB serial number string is just a string - and can contain non-numeric characters.

Comment: Thanks for your response:)